# Why is systemd not starting my service on boot, while I have a Wants set?

Tags: linux, systemd

I want my service (depending on PostgreSQL) to start on boot, so I `enable`d it using `systemd`, and in the `.service` file I say it `Wants` the postgres service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
Wants=postgresql-12

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/myservice
ExecStart=/path/to/myservice/my_service -d

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`myservice` does not start on boot, because the PostgreSQL server is not there yet (I can see that in my logs). When starting it later with `systemctl start myservice`, it starts fine, so it seems the `.service` file is valid.

Why is `systemctl` not waiting for Postgres before starting my service? I tried to check also with `systemd-analyze blame`, but that seems to only show running services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wants=` does not imply `After=`, so you need to specify both.

Though in some cases it does, but mostly only when a *target* "wants" another unit. (So when multi-user.target has Wants=your.service, it'll imply an After=your.service.) But this is an exception; the general rule is that ordering is not automatically set from dependencies.

Also, both Wants= and After= require a "full" unit name – even though 'postgresql-12' is enough for systemctl, you must specify it as `postgresql-12.service` within unit files.